# .addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ ... }) To Fat Arrow. How does one access properties within the scope of the function?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

I am trying to access the properties of an HTMLElement within the scope of a fat arrow function.  My goal is to read when a user has scrolled to the bottom of a virtualScroll element.

I have a function that successfully consoles logs the end of the virtual scroll, however I've struggled to get that into a variable that Typescript can use.  Here is the working code...

```
let virtualScroll = document.getElementById("virtualScroll")  as HTMLElement;
virtualScroll.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
  let x: boolean = false;
  if(this.scrollTop + this.clientHeight == this.scrollHeight){
    x = true;
  };
  console.log('virtualScroll END?:  ', x);
  return(x);  // I can't seem to use this either :<
})
```

---

However, my lack of knowledge on how the scope works in fat arrow functions has limited me from using "this.scrollTop" and other "this." property variables.

```
virtualScroll.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(e).scrollHeight );
})
```

What is logged from the second function is always "undefined" so clearly I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not the best solution, but I hacked something together that works.  Here is a bit of setup that is required.

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    '(window:resize)': 'onResize($event)',
  }
})
```

Variables...

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport)
viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
topOffset: number = 80;  // A reference to my CSS offset for my <app-bar>.
```

Init...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.clientHeight = window.innerHeight - this.topOffset;
}
```

Resize Event...

```
onResize(event){
  this.clientHeight = event.target.innerHeight - this.topOffset;
}
```

And finally, the star of the show, getting the virtual scroll location!

```
virtualScrollLocation(){
      if(this.clientHeight + this.viewport.measureScrollOffset("top") == this.viewport.measureRenderedContentSize()){
        console.log("END")
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `function` to `arrow function`

Simply changing this

`virtualScroll.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {`